# Why does match returns None while findall doesn't?

Tags: python, regex, match

I have this string:

```
s = "mage('Images/mpins/pin5_Jul1.png', new"
```

This is my pattern:

```
patt_img = r'\w+.png'
```

Why does

```
re.findall(patt_img,s)
```

return

```
['pin5_Jul1.png']
```

but `match` returns `None`?

```
m = re.match(patt_img,s)
>>> type(m)
<type 'NoneType'>`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `match` matches only starting from the beginning of the string.

> If zero or more characters *at the beginning* of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance.
>
> If you want to locate a match *anywhere* in string, use `search()` instead.

Comment: Eh, yes. I keep forgetting about this. Thanks.